# Add column "last run date/time" to views

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins by default has three columns about the last build:

- Last Success
- Last Failure
- Last Duration

Views can be sorted by those columns and that's great and all, but it doesn't allow me to sort in a way that I can easily see what order projects were recently built in. **What I'm looking for** is a way to have an extra column:

- **Last "Run"** (or some equivalent term)

Preferably the column would even be a timestamp/datetime as opposed to a time*span*, but that'd be bonus.

What I've tried so far:

- Go through the "Configure System" settings;
- Search the plugins (found [ZenTimestamp](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ZenTimestamp+Plugin) and [ExtraColumns](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extra+Columns+Plugin), but they don't fit the bill);
- Use some [Google-fu](https://www.google.com/search?q=Jenkins%20add%20column%20for%20last%20build);

Is this just not possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My Google-fu has conjured some results. This isn't possible in default Jenkins. There is an issue in Jenkin's issue tracker, [JENKINS-7844](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7844):

> **A Filter to sort jobs by last run time.**
>   There are sort options for:
>   S W Job Last Success Last Failure ↓   Last Duration
>
> Please add one for Last Ran.
>
> Useful for seeing what has run in the last couple of hours/days (especially when there is a major build failure).

The issue was created October 2010, and was closed October 31st 2014 with "Status: Resolved" and this comment:

> Compact Columns solves this issue

So: check out [the Compact Columns plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Compact+Columns).

Comment: Compact Columns does not display values for aborted builds. So if the last N builds were aborted, it displays N-1 builds run time as last run time or nothing if no build ever finished.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in Jenkins by default.

You could however use the [Compact Columns](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Compact+Columns) plugin as suggested in [Jenkins issue 7844](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7844):

1. install the plugin
2. add the column `Compact Column: Statuses w/Options` with option `Only show the last status`
3. sort on the newly added column

Comment: Aye, that's the plugin I also mentioned in my original answer.

Comment: That doesn't work for aborted runs, e.g. due to timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something really different, but that can help you see the latests build of your jenkins is the link "Build history".
There, you can see the lastests build you have done, with a nice timeline.

The columns are:
- bullet (red / green or blue / ...)
- project
- time since that build
- status
- console output button

The view is available globally and by folder.

But, you have one line per build, and not by project.

According to your real needs, that can help (or not).

My two cents

Comment: This solution worked Multibranch pipelines. Compact Columns does not work with multibranch pipelines (which we use).

Answer (score 1):

You can install compact columns plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Compact+Columns